# Automatically open a file send via email

Tags: python, email, download

I am currently in the position where one of my home devices sends the data of each day in form of a .csv file via email.
Thereby I can tell the device to whatever email (also multiple) it should send this file at the end of the day.
The email only contains this one file attached to it.

So, this is what I am working with.

I now would like to create my own statistics of the data using python, where I could add the data every day and calculate, plot etc.

The question is, how can I automatically download a file which is sent to me via email? I simply have no idea where to start. I was thinking about setting up an raspberry pi with some sort of email adress, but as you can tell I simply have no idea...

It would be great if someone would have a suggestion, or also maybe a link or documentation on stuff like this where I can teach it myself.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to medium [article](https://medium.com/@sdoshi579/to-read-emails-and-download-attachments-in-python-6d7d6b60269) that has instructions how to download attachments that came with the email

The program could read the csv file with [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) library. You can do all sorts of data manipulation and also some plotting with pandas. But If you want to have really good plots you could use [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/index.html) and [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/)

All this you could run in cloud maybe? I have zero experience with running projects in cloud so I can't really tell, but I've heard that you can do this. Maybe you could use [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-python-application-using-aws-app-runner/) to do this?

That's how I would do it.

Googling any of the keywords such as pandas or AWS gives you tons and tons of tutorials.

Comment: Thank you very much! This article looks quite nice. I hope it will help me:)